# Bash String concatenation and get content

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash loop, I'm trying to read the all variables:

```
var1="hello1"

var2="hello2"

var3="hello3"

for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
 ab=var$i
 # Now ab == var1, I want to echo $var1 

done
```

I'm trying to get dynamically var(1)(2)(3) and get out the String of it.

**Edit:**

The point here is how to concatenation variables like `ab=var$i`
and using the `ab` variable (`var1` for example) as a variable, I mean to get the `var1` value `hello1`
I didn't mean how to do it to this specific example, and not with arrays.

Hope I have clarified myself.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

Comment: @ork edited my answer after your edit, can be done with brace expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var1="hello1"
var2="hello2"
var3="hello3"

for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
    ab=var$i
    echo ${!ab}
done
```

I'm not sure it is the best solution to your larger problem, but it is the direct solution to your immediate request.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach:

```
var1="hello1"
var2="hello2"
var3="hello3"

eval echo\ $var{1..3}\;
```

Is expanded to:

```
echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var3
```

**Ouput:**

```
hello1 
hello2 
hello3
```